# Append a file to a existing form in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to append an image to my existing form.

Form:

```js
data: () => ({
    form: new Form({
        serverid: '',
        name: '',
        ipaddress: '',
        port: '',
        description: '',
        coverimg: null
    }),
    url: '',
    remember: false
}),
```

Methods:

```js
methods: {
    previewImage(e) {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        this.url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        let data = new FormData()
        this.form.coverimg = data.append('coverimg', file)
        console.log(data.get('coverimg'))
    },
    async addServer () {
        let data
        try {
            const response = await this.form.post('/server/add')
            data = response.data
            this.$router.push('/' + data.serverid)
        } catch (e) {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

However, the image does not get appended to the form. I dont want the image to be directly uploaded, because the user has to submit the form himself after he entered all the other informations needed.